# does avro C implementation support streaming rather than file output?

Tags: c, avro

I have gone through the C document at [avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/api/c/index.html)
and I see that I can get only avro output to file. How do I get the serialized output to a buffer so that I can send over a tcp socket. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just write to the socket?

Comment: _Any help is much appreciated._  Hmmm,  a thank you comment for the only answer might be nice.

Answer (score 3):

There is an `avro_writer_memory()` exactly for this case, it takes buffer pointer and length as parameters and gives you `avro_writer_t` that can be used in regular write functions. You can find its usage in tests, like [this](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/c/tests/test_avro_1379.c) or [this](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/c/tests/test_avro_1691.c). The minimum example is going to be something like this (outputting encoded value to stderr, so better redirect that to some file and examine it after program run):

```
#include <avro.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static const char json_schema[] = "{ \"type\": \"string\" }";

int main(void)
{
    char buf[1024];
    avro_writer_t writer;
    avro_schema_t schema;
    avro_value_iface_t* iface;
    avro_value_t val;
    size_t len;

    if (avro_schema_from_json_literal(json_schema, &schema) != 0) {
        printf("failed to initialize schema\n");
        goto out;
    }
    if ((writer = avro_writer_memory(buf, sizeof(buf))) == NULL) {
        printf("failed to initialize writer\n");
        goto out_schema;
    }
    if ((iface = avro_generic_class_from_schema(schema)) == NULL) {
        printf("failed to get class from schema\n");
        goto out_writer;
    }
    if (avro_generic_value_new(iface, &val) != 0) {
        printf("failed to create new value\n");
        goto out_iface;
    }
    if (avro_value_reset(&val) != 0) {
        printf("failed to reset value\n");
        goto out_val;
    }
    if (avro_value_set_string(&val, "some string wrapped by avro") != 0) {
        printf("failed to set value string\n");
        goto out_val;
    }
    if (avro_value_write(writer, &val) != 0) {
        printf("failed to write value into the buffer\n");
        goto out_val;
    }
    len = avro_writer_tell(writer);
    printf("got %lu bytes\n", (unsigned long)len);
    if (write(STDERR_FILENO, buf, len) != len) {
        printf("failed to write to stderr, oops\n");
        goto out_val;
    }
out_val:
    avro_value_decref(&val);
out_iface:
    avro_value_iface_decref(iface);
out_writer:
    avro_writer_free(writer);
out_schema:
    avro_schema_decref(schema);
out:
    return 0;
}
```

Also, there is an `avro_writer_memory_set_dest()` that allows to set new buffer to use by the existing writer.